# VBA - Excel sheet wont save to current directory - defaults to My Documents

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save 2 sheets of a xlsm file as MSDOS text filea with a .bat extension so I can run them as scripts, and have it save them to the current directory.  What would cause it to default to My Documents instead?

I'm not a coder - I used Record Macro to create it and then edited it to take out the specific path.  I actually had this working until I added the ActiveWorkbook.Save at the beginning, and the ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False at the end so I wouldn't lose the formatting by accidentally saving it manually.  Now it saves the files to My Documents no matter what I try.  I can't imagine that would cause it, and taking those 2 lines out didn't fix it.  What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Sheets("Copy Script").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "copy.bat", FileFormat:= _
    xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
Sheets("Plot Script").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "plot.bat", FileFormat:= _
    xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\copy.bat", FileFormat:= xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Why it stopped working the other way will remain a mystery, I suppose.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks